# Texmaker - LaTeX Error: File `bm.sty' not found

Tags: miktex, texmaker, paths

I was trying to use pstricks in Texmaker and wanted to manually install a package. However, since it didn't work I downloaded MiKTeX and I must have accidentally destroyed my settings and the paths. Now not even the normal PDF is generated anymore. I tried to uninstall both Texmaker and MiKTeX but it still does not work and I get the following error:
*! LaTeX Error: File `bm.sty' not found.*
Does anyone know how I can fix this error or how I can exactly see what is going wrong?
Thank you very much in advance for your time and your help!
Kind regards,
Ferdi

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! bm is part of the `latex-tools` miktex package. This being said, did you install Texmaker *after* installing MiKTeX?

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks for your answer! I previously had installed MiKTeX 2.9 but then downloaded MiKTeX. When I try to uninstall MiKteX 2.9 there is an error saying that copystart_admin.exe could not be found and I don't really know how I can fix that or to at least uninstall both programs and re-trying it...

Comment: I'm not too sure of what can be done, but you might try deleting the directories where TeXmaker and MiKTeX are installed, then delete what's remaining in the registry with a tool like `ccleaner`? Unless, of course someone has a  better idea…

Comment: Dear Bernard, I have followed your advice and it is working again, thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad when I can help!